# Difference in capacity of QR code when calculating manually and when referring to online references

Tags: qr-code

I am working on a QR code generator in python, my main reference so far was [Thonky's QR Code Tutorial](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/).

According to a table on the website ([Error Correction Code Words and Block Information](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/error-correction-table)) a version 1 QR code will always hold 26 codewords (some data codewords & others error codewords), 26 codewords is 208 bits or in other words 208 pixels of data and error correction information.

To verify that I manually checked the number of pixels, I also verified that by calculating the number of pixels taken by the finder patterns, the timing patterns, and the format information.

Now when working with a version 2 QR code, according to the [table](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/error-correction-table) on Thonky's website, a version 2 has 44 codewords or 352 bits/pixels.

When generating the QR code I notice that there are 7 empty pixels, upon further inspection I come to figure out that there are 359 empty pixels in a version 2 QR code.

I manually counted the pixels to find 359 pixels, and I also calculated the pixels by finding the total number of pixels (25 x 25) or 625 and then subtracting the size of the finder patterns, the timing patterns, the separators, the format information, and the alignment patterns.

My data is 352 bits long, and it can not be 359 bits because padding comes in 8 bits, so I am not sure if I am missing some format information that I am not putting in version 2 code or if it is something else.

The same goes for the version 3 QR code, according to the table it holds 560 bits, but according to my calculation it holds 567 bits.

Is there a reason why I can count 359 empty pixels, but my data expands only 352 pixels?

Here are some images throughout the steps of the construction

[image: QR Code without data]

[image: QR Code with data & without format information]

[image: R Code with data & with format information]

Edit:

After more research and looking up the reason that counting the number of pixels is different than the number of bytes the QR code version stores. I found this image on [wikipidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:QR_Ver3_Codeword_Ordering.svg), it shows the last 7 pixels to be "unused", however, there is no explanation on why that is the case. This image shows a version 3 QR code, that also requires interleaving, but I think it is quite similar to my issue.